# Recursive iterate, replace nested children keys to numeric

Tags: javascript

Need your help guys

I have nested object with infinity nesting.
How I can reorganize `children` keys to `numeric` keys?

From this:

```js
{
  children: [
    {
      taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a16715e45308",
      opts: {},
      children: [
        {
          taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
          opts: {},
          children: [
            taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
            opts: {},
            children: []
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
}
```

To this:

```js
{
  1: {
    2: {
      3: {
        4: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying use forEach and recursive function, but any result.

Comment: How should the numbering work if you have items with more than one child? (Or is that not going to happen?)

Comment: Looks like a level-order traversal to me

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how much sense this explanation makes but... Here the idea is to loop through a queue that gets built as you go. The items in the queue being the old data object and a reference to a new one that's being created as you go. A number gets incremented on each iteration to serve as the new key values. Each iteration a member of the queue gets removed and serves as the basis to add more items to the queue if the current object has children.

The following numbers the items horizontally down the tree (or breadth-first / level-order traversal):

```js
const data = {
  children: [
    {
      taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a16715e45308",
      opts: {},
      children: [
        {
          taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
          opts: {},
          children: [
            {
              taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
              opts: {},
              children: []
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
          opts: {},
          children: [
            {
              taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
              opts: {},
              children: [
                {
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  children: []
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
      ],
    }
  ],
};

const get_numeric_keys = (data) => {
  let number = 0;
  const result = {};
  const queue = [[data, result]];
  
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    const [obj, new_obj] = queue.shift();
    
    number++;
    new_obj[number] = obj?.children?.length > 0 ? {} : '';
    
    if(obj?.children?.length > 0) {
      queue.push(...obj.children.map( (child) => [child, new_obj[number]] ));
    }
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(get_numeric_keys(data));
```

This version numbers the items by going down as far as possible first (or depth-first traversal):

```js
const data = {
  children: [
    {
      taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a16715e45308",
      opts: {},
      children: [
        {
          taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
          opts: {},
          children: [
            {
              taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
              opts: {},
              children: []
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
          opts: {},
          children: [
            {
              taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
              opts: {},
              children: [
                {
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  children: []
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
      ],
    }
  ],
};

const get_numeric_keys = (data) => {
  let number = 0;
  const result = {};
  const queue = [[data, result]];
  
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    const [obj, new_obj] = queue.pop(); // pop instead of shift
    
    number++;
    new_obj[number] = obj?.children?.length > 0 ? {} : '';
    
    if(obj?.children?.length > 0) {
      // the new items go into the queue in reverse order here.
      queue.push(...obj.children.map( (child) => [child, new_obj[number]] ).reverse());
    }
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(get_numeric_keys(data));
```

Comment: This is called a level-order traversal.

Comment: Thanks @vr Do you know what the one where you go down as far as possible first is called?

Comment: That would be a depth-first search or depth-first traversal.

Comment: Thanks @ vr . From looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal it looks like level-order and breadth-first are synonymous (if I've understood it).

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {
  children: [{
    taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a16715e45308",
    opts: {},
    children: [{
      taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
      opts: {},
      children: [{
        taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
        opts: {},
        children: []
      }]
    }],
  }],
}

const result = replace(data)

console.log(result)

function replace(object, level = 1) {
  if (object !== undefined) {
    return {
      [level]: replace(object.children[0], level + 1)
    }
  }
  return ''
}
```

Comment: `object.children[0]` this we have more than one children

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work:
I am not sure why it works, but I've got some points (may help solving the problem):

1. Determine when to stop recursion
2. Thinking in TypeScript does help

Note: I don't understand what is your question here: what traversal ordering do you want? in BFS or DFS? I am answering in DFS now because you've mentioned "recursion".

```js
// type ObjType = { children: [] | ObjType[]; };
const obj = {
  children: [
    {
      taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a16715e45308",
      opts: {},
      children: [
        {
          taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-893d-a248cae411208",
          opts: {},
          children: [
            { // [+] Curly Brackets
              taskId: "e3f241f8-c879-4118-89112d-s248cae411208",
              opts: {},
              children: []
            },
            {
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      children: [
        {
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
};

// type MappedType = { [key: number]: string | MappedType; };
// {
//   1: {
//     2: {
//       3: {
//         4: ""
//       },
//       5: {
//         6: ""
//       }
//     }
//   },
//   7: {
//     8: {
//       9: ""
//     }
//   }
// }


// obj: ObjType, key is referenced
const mapper = (obj, key = [0]) => {
  key[0] += 1;
  const children = obj.children;
  if (children.length === 0) {
    return { [key[0]++]: '' };
  }

  // mapped: MappedType
  const mapped = {};
  for (const child of obj.children) {
    mapped[key[0]] = mapper(child, key); // key[0] is modified after returning
  }
  return mapped;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapper(obj), undefined, 2));
```